# CELLPHONE (ANDROID) TO PC WIFI SHARING

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I Just want to ask if its possible for a laptop to share the internet connection of an android phone.The phone is using vpn connection to get internet from my simcard newtwork provider? And HOW?

Thanks!
Monsai

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, you want your PC to connect to your phone's internet connection?
Tethering, more like it, right?
If so, then there should be an option in your wireless networks settings (Tethering/Mobile Hotspot) which you can enable to allow your PC to gain connectivity to your phone's internet connection.